# Why are Mac computers so good at h264 video decoding?

Tags: macos, video, javafx, h.264, hardware-acceleration

Right now I'm working on an application that uses JavaFX and it allows you to seek through videos. All of our videos are recorded with the same settings as far as bitrate and GOP structure. With the exact same video, seeking through the video on Mac computers look awesome and the screen updates at a really fast rate.

Basically, all the Mac computers in our office are able to play the h264 encoded videos back in reverse at 30 FPS without any problem. It looks the same as it does going forward.

On Windows machines though, I can't see the video actually update on the UI when playing in reverse at 30 FPS. I have to slow it down to about 10 in order for the screen to update.

Both computers are using hardware acceleration and have similar specs. As a matter of fact, we have a Mac with a 2.4 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM that performs better than any of our Windows computers with higher specs when seeking through videos.

What things can contribute to this? Do Mac computers have some special hardware that enables this? Is it possible to get this kind of performance out of a Windows machine?

Comment: Reverse playback of temporally compressed video is an unnatural playback operation. Its performance primarily depends on quality of software and how accurately it implements reverse playback (rearranges GOPs, decodes them in direction opposite to playback direction, then rearranges frames again). Apparently you did not come across respective player for Windows. This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, where you are supposed to ask specific programming questions.

Comment: I've used the same player on Mac and Windows. I wrote it using JavaFX. Plus, where would this question belong then? Ask Different? Programmers?

Comment: "Same player" does not necessarily mean exactly same code/implementation on different platform. In Windows, for example, there is no stock support for reverse H.264 playback, so every player is on its own - most are simply not capable to play backward at all. SuperUser, Ask Different look more appropriate for the question, I suppose.

Comment: @arjabbar this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**